# Ajax during call and on error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that gets the location of a user and pulls the city and province from my database. When you click the button to trigger the call I want the input box to disappear and be replaced with a loading gif.

If it is unable to return anything, the box should come back.

I have tried using this:

```
    .ajaxStart(function(data) {
        $('#location').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })
```

But it prevents the script from doing anything.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var formData = {
        'latitude'              :  ''+ position.coords.latitude +'' ,
        'longitude'             : ''+ position.coords.longitude +'',
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'php/includes/get_postal_rem.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'html', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
    })
    // using the done promise callback
    .done(function(data) {
            $('#location').val(data);
    });


    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the function to disable the input box just before your // process the form comment i.e.

```
$('#location').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

// process the form comment.
```

By the way, you'll also need to add the code to show the progress gif and also enable the textbox and hide this gif after your ajax returns (or if it errors out)